# Google Analytics BigQuery Export Event Count Issue

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get a total events count for a particular event in BigQuery along with a custom dimension for versions of the site.

This query works perfect but does not include my custom dimension:

```
SELECT
hits.eventInfo.eventCategory AS eventCategory,
COUNT(*) AS total_events
FROM `ga_sessions_*`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20200630'
AND totals.visits = 1
AND hits.type = 'EVENT' 
AND hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Cart CTA' 
GROUP BY 
hits.eventInfo.eventCategory
```

But when I add the UNNEST for customDimensions, I get a total that is twice the correct total.

```
SELECT
hits.eventInfo.eventCategory AS eventCategory,
COUNT(*) AS total_events
FROM `ga_sessions_*`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) AS cd
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20200630'
AND totals.visits = 1
AND hits.type = 'EVENT' 
AND hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Cart CTA' 
GROUP BY 
hits.eventInfo.eventCategory
```

I think there is something wrong with customDimension unnest, but I don't know how to solve.  I've tried using `LEFT JOIN` with the `UNNEST` but I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

> I think there is something wrong with customDimension unnest

This is by design! When you do UNNEST for the row that has N records in that unnested column - you actually generate N rows in place of that one row. So, obviously COUNT(*) will be different ...

> I don't know how to solve

... unless you filter by specific value of that unnested field

Comment: I'm not sure what I should filter for.  Should my total_events column have a CASE to count something specific?

Comment: this depends on business logic of your use case. you can add this to WHERE clause like you done for `hits.type = 'EVENT'`